# MPI program gives MPI- channel initialization failed how can I solve this error?

Tags: python, c, mpi

I am running a simple MPI program to crack encrypted password. The program completely compiled but if I run **mpirun -n 3 ./passwordcracking.py ./a | grep Time** in my command line I am unable to run MPI program

The program shows:

```
MPID_Init(162).......: channel initialization failed
```

And When I write python before `./passwordcracking.py`

Another error shows:

```
HYDU_create_process (utils/launch/launch.c:74): execvp error on file python (No such file or directory)
```

[image: Screen Evidence]

Comment: Please include the results, not pictures of results in your question. Sometimes it is difficult to read content in images, and they can't be searched or indexed in the same way as text.

Comment: The results are already here. The picture of the results is completely supplementary.